# Como validar si un usuario esta logeado

Tags: asp.net

estoy realizando una aplicación web con asp.NET y quería saber como validar si el usuario esta ya logeado o no.

Tengo mi InicioSesion.aspx donde se encuentra el formulario de login con su respectivo boton que redirige a la pagina de inicio. Mis dudas son las siguientes, como puedo yo hacer para que cuando me redirija a esa pagina, me redirija con el usuario ya cargado es decir validar que ya estoy adentro del sistema.

InicioSesion.aspx:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)usuarioNegocio.ObtenerUsuario(usuarioEntidad);
            Session["Dni"] = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            Session["Nombre"] = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();
            Session["Apellido"] = dt.Rows[0][6].ToString();
            Session["Email"] = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            Session["Rol"] = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
            Session["Direccion"] = dt.Rows[0][7].ToString();
            Session["Contrasenia"] = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
            Server.Transfer("../PaginaInicial.aspx");
```

UsuarioNegocio.aspx

```
public DataTable ObtenerUsuario(UsuarioEntidad usuario)
        {
            string consulta = "Select * from Usuario where Mail = '" + usuario.EmailUsuario + "' and Contraseña = '" + usuario.Contra + "'";
            AccesoDatos acc = new AccesoDatos();
            return acc.ObtenerTabla("Usuario", consulta);
        }
```

Esta es la función que obtiene los datos del usuario a través de una consulta de la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Para eso tienes que setear una cookie en el método del controller al que haces referencia al iniciar sesión.

Lo haces con:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Session["Dni"], false);
```

**ANOTACIONES**:

1.Para usar esta función es importante setear el loginUrl en el tag authentication mode en el Web.config.

2. Session["Dni"] hace referencia al identificador de la entidad.
3. El campo booleano indica si la conexión tiene un *time-out*
4. Al finalizar hay que "limpiar" dicha cookie, con el método FormsAuthentication.SignOut()